# compare two array of hash in general without any specific key in ruby

Tags: arrays, json, ruby, hash, compare

I wanted to compare 2 arrays of hashes for all values without any specific key `"d"`. Please help in comparing 2 arrays of hashes in a way which iterates all values in the array of hashes.

```
A = [
{​​​​​​​​​​​"a"=>"1000", "b"=>"0", "c"=>"3", "d"=>"1", "e"=>"3", "f"=>"status"}​​​​​​​​​​​,


{​​​​​​​​​​​"a"=>"2", "e"=>"0", "b"=>"0", "c"=>"4", "d"=>"3", "e="3","f"=>"s-2"}​​​​​​​​​​​,


{​​​​​​​​​​​"a"=>"0", "b"=>"0", "c"=>"1", "d"=>"3", "e"=>"1", "f"=>"s-01"}​​​​​​​​​​ ]


B= [

{​​​​​​​​​​​"a"=>"1000", "b"=>"0", "c"=>"3", "d"=>"1", "e"=>"3", "f"=>"status"}​​​​​​​​​​​,


{​​​​​​​​​​​"a"=>"2", "e"=>"0", "b"=>"0", "c"=>"4", "d"=>"3", "e="3","f"=>"s-2"}​​​​​​​​​​​,


{​​​​​​​​​​​"a"=>"0", "b"=>"0", "c"=>"1", "d"=>"3", "e"=>"1", "f"=>"s-01"}​​​​​​​​​​ ]
```

I have tried below code but I wanted to compare all elements without the specific key `"d"`. Please help!

```
A.each do |e_hash|  
B.each do |a_hash|
if (a_hash["d"].to_s == e_hash["d"].to_s)  
    e_hash.each do |k,v|

puts v if k == "d"  if (a_hash[k].to_s != v.to_s)        
count += 1 
else     
count   
end     
end
end
```

Comment: What is the expected output when comparing the above example hashes?

Comment: i need to get the matching pairs by comparing both the arrays

Comment: So in your above example, you want to return the full `A` array, because `A` and `B` are the same? Perhaps it would be easier when you posted an example in which not all hashes were equal? Then it would be easier to see what to return and what not to return.

Comment: i am a newbie and so wanted to know the code to compare

Answer (score 0):

When you want to compare two hashes without a specific key then you can use

```
hash_1 = { "a" => 0, "b" => 0, "c" => 0 }
hash_2 = { "a" => 0, "b" => 0, "c" => 1 }

hash_1.tap { |hs| hs.delete("c") } == hash_2.tap { |hs| hs.delete("c") }
#=> true
```

In your above example, you could do this:

```
A = [
  {"a"=>"1000", "b"=>"0", "c"=>"3", "d"=>"1", "e"=>"3", "f"=>"status"},
  {"a"=>"2", "e"=>"0", "b"=>"0", "c"=>"4", "d"=>"3", "e"=>"3", "f"=>"s-2"},
  {"a"=>"0", "b"=>"0", "c"=>"1", "d"=>"3", "e"=>"1", "f"=>"s-01"} 
]
B = [
  {"a"=>"1000", "b"=>"0", "c"=>"3", "d"=>"1", "e"=>"3", "f"=>"status"},
  {"a"=>"2", "e"=>"0", "b"=>"0", "c"=>"4", "d"=>"3", "e"=>"3", "f"=>"s-2"},
  {"a"=>"0", "b"=>"0", "c"=>"1", "d"=>"3", "e"=>"1", "f"=>"s-01"} 
]
A.each do |e_hash|  
  B.each do |a_hash|
    if e_hash.tap { |hs| hs.delete("d") } == a_hash.tap { |hs| hs.delete("d") }
      puts "Equal hash found: #{e_hash}"
    end
  end     
end
#=> Equal hash found: {"a"=>"1000", "b"=>"0", "c"=>"3", "e"=>"3", "f"=>"status"}
#   Equal hash found: {"a"=>"2", "e"=>"3", "b"=>"0", "c"=>"4", "f"=>"s-2"}
#   Equal hash found: {"a"=>"0", "b"=>"0", "c"=>"1", "e"=>"1", "f"=>"s-01"}
```